# Split app in ui5 the back button doesnot work

Tags: sapui5

I tried to implement split app feature in my mobile application .But after navigating to the Detail2 page a "back" navigation button is put , which does not work when pressed .

I have placed my code below : (Revert back if you need more info on that)
view.js file (content) :

```
sap.ui.jsview("split_app.first_view", {
    getControllerName : function() {
        return "split_app.first_view";
    },

    
    createContent : function(oController) {
        

        var olist1 = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            type: sap.m.ListType.Active,
            title: "to detail 1",
            tap: function(){
                    osplit.toDetail("detail1");
                }
        });
        var olist2 = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            type: sap.m.ListType.Active,
            title: "to detail 2",
            tap: function(){
                    osplit.toDetail("detail2");
                }
        });
        
        var otext = new sap.m.Label({
            text: "first label",
        });
        
        var osplit = new sap.m.SplitApp("split");
        
        var odetail1 = new sap.m.Page("detail1", {
            title: "first details",
            content: [
                        otext
                      ]
        });
        var odetail2 = new sap.m.Page("detail2",{
            title: "second Details",
            showNavButton: true,
            navButtonPress: function(){
                osplit.toMaster("masterPage");
                              app.back();
            },
            
            content: [
                      new sap.m.Label({
                          text: "second label"
                      })
                      ]
        });
        
        var omaster1 = new sap.m.Page("masterPage", {
            title: "master page",
            content:[
                      new sap.m.List({

                          items : [ olist1, olist2 ]
                      }) ]
        });
        
        osplit.addMasterPage(omaster1);
        osplit.addDetailPage(odetail1).addDetailPage(odetail2);
        osplit.setMode("ShowHideMode");
        
        return new sap.m.Page({
            title: "Title",
            content: [
                    osplit  
            ]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to navigate one step back in your Detail Area (right side) you can call the backDetail() function of your SplitApp Object when clicking on the back button (navButtonPress):

```
osplit.backDetail();
```

The same function works for back navigation in your Master Area (left side):

```
osplit.backMaster();
```

If you want to navigate back within your app object, make sure that there is a previous page you come from and all pages are known to the App object (probably in your index.html file):
I´ve just tested your code and it worked for me to navigate within the SplitApp using above mentioned functions as well as navigating back in the App with the following declaration (in your index or wherever you host the App object):

```
var app = new sap.m.App();

var init = sap.ui.view({
    id : "idinit",
    viewName : "stackovertest.init",
    type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
})

var page = sap.ui.view({
    id : "idsplit_app1",
    viewName : "stackovertest.split_app",
    type : sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
});
app.addPage(init);
app.addPage(page);
```

After coming from the init page you can use

```
app.back();
```

Hopefully this helps you.